# Pandas pivot table with prefix to columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df = C1 A1. A2. A3. Type
     A   1.   5. 2.   AG
     A   7.   3. 8.   SC
```

And I want to create:

```
df = C1 A1_AG A1_SC A2_AG A2_SC
     A   1.    7.   5.     3
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rather use a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
(df.melt('Type')
   .assign(col=lambda d: d['Type']+'_'+d['variable'])
   .set_index('col')[['value']].T
)
```

Output:

```
col    AG_A1  SC_A1  AG_A2  SC_A2  AG_A3  SC_A3
value      1      7      5      3      2      8
```

##### with additional columns(s):

```
(df.melt(['C1', 'Type'])
   .assign(col=lambda d: d['Type']+'_'+d['variable'])
   .pivot(index=['C1'], columns='col', values='value')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col C1  AG_A1  AG_A2  AG_A3  SC_A1  SC_A2  SC_A3
0    A      1      5      2      7      3      8
```

Comment: Added an index col that should not be affected, can you pls adjust?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['C1','Type']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  C1  A1_AG  A1_SC  A2_AG  A2_SC  A3_AG  A3_SC
0  A    1.0    7.0    5.0    3.0    2.0    8.0
```

Comment: I was just adding this variant when you posted, sorry

Comment: I'm removing it, you can use `'_'.join` in `map` btw.

Comment: @jezrael Added an index col that should not be affected, can you pls adjust?

Answer (score 1):

One convenience option with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_wider(index = 'C1', names_from = 'Type')

  C1  A1_AG  A1_SC  A2_AG  A2_SC  A3_AG  A3_SC
0  A    1.0    7.0    5.0    3.0    2.0    8.0
```

Of course, you can skip the convenience function and use `pivot` directly:

```py
result = df.pivot(index='C1', columns='Type')
result.columns = result.columns.map('_'.join)
result.reset_index()

  C1  A1_AG  A1_SC  A2_AG  A2_SC  A3_AG  A3_SC
0  A    1.0    7.0    5.0    3.0    2.0    8.0
```